# CAS protection against CSRF attacks

Tags: authentication, cookies, csrf

A website based on [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) uses `central authentication service (cas)` for login. I'd like to know if additional `csrf` protection needs to be provided with Struts in case `cas` doesn't provide that.

Also, when credentials are submitted, `cas` generates a token in URL form. If I copy this URL and use it later, the user is authenticated and redirected to the home page.

As I'm not logging in, but just using the token URL, why is this happening? Is this a security vulnerability?

Comment: I don't know CAS but knowing similar technologies, I strongly suspect the answer is "no". The application needs to have its own CSRF protection. You can do this in struts using the token interceptor, and placing s:token tags in all forms. http://nickcoblentz.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/csrf-prevention-in-struts-2.html

Comment: @paj28: Yes I have seen that link before, but want to confirm if we are not doing repetition. There may be a chance that CAS provides a mechanism for that.

Comment: Personally, I'd do a quick pen test to check if it's vulnerable, just on one form. This may not be great advice for you if you're not a pen tester, but here's a relevant methodology: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSRF_(OWASP-SM-005)

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but must...get...internet...points...

Maybe you're just referring to CSRF protection on the login page, but if you mean in general:

I'm still new to the CAS protocol, but my understanding is that the only time validation happens is at the beginning before you have a session id in the service application itself. Once this is generated, no more contact with the CAS server is needed and no service ticket is needed, so CAS's ST cannot protect you from CSRF attacks.

See:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html

I imagine the token you mention is the "ST" (service ticket) parameter. Again, new to this stuff, but it sounds to me like you shouldn't be able to use that more than once, so maybe that is/was a bug, or maybe the spec has changed:

https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html#311-service-ticket-properties

However, if you still have your session cookie, you don't need the ST, so maybe that was producing that behavior.